# I need to extract domain from email but i get @domain.com i dont need the @ at the start of the domain

Tags: regex, python-2.7, google-app-engine-python

I need to **extract domain from email but I got @domain.com**. I dont need the `@` at the start of the domain

```
class ExtractDomain(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):

    user = (str(users.get_current_user().email()))
    domain = re.search("@[\w.]+", user)
    thisdomain = domain.group()


    template_values = {'user': user, 'thisdomain':thisdomain}
    template = jinja2_env.get_template('templates/domain.html')
    self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is `@[\w.]+`, which matches `@words.com`, all you have to do is do something with the `@` so it's not in your result.

Solution 1: **Lookbehind**

Lookbehinds tests if previous characters match, while not changing the result. `(?<=@)[\w.]+`

Solution 2: **Capture groups**

You can specify which part you want, in your case `@([\w.]+)` in brackets, then calling it by $1. However, this would require slight modifications to your code.

For the first solution you only need to change the line the regex is in: `domain = re.search("(?<=@)[\w.\-]+", user)` Added `\-` so some multiple-word domain names get processed, not necessary for the problem.

Comment: @TJ not much is needed to be changed, updated my answer

Comment: @TJ as a side note, you might want to add `-` into your character class `(?<=@)[\w.\-]+` so `test@some-domain.com` gets processed correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing parentheses:

```
1- domain = re.search( "@([\w.]+)", user ).group(1)
```

OR  strip first character off afterwards:

```
2- domain = domain[1:]
```

Not sure if this is a proper way to do it (don't do much with python) but it works.